# Приложения

Tags: дефис

как  пишутся данные слова через дефис?
девочка золушка,шоколад "Цирк",красавица зорька

Answer (score 2):

Девочка-золушка, шоколад "Цирк", красавица зорька. А почему так - смотрите правила в школьном учебнике